# how to click the div in css using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

In this div contains load more, and i want to click in this div.

```
<div class="clearfix zs-load-more" data-entity_id="8913" 
         data-profile_action="reviews-top" data-limit="5" data-page="1">
 <div class="load-more">
  Load More <span class="zs-load-more-count">92</span></div></div>
```

main url of this page.

Comment: I recommend checking out Geb http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.9.2/ it makes testing webpages so much easier than plain selenium

Comment: is the code for scrolling required? It works pretty much without it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the below code to click on load more

```
driver.findElement(By.className("load-more")).click();
```

Comment: not working. have a look in the link http://www.zomato.com/ncr/pirates-of-grill-mg-road-gurgaon/reviews

Comment: how to send the data-entity_id="8913"  any idea

Comment: i have tested the above code in firefox and chrome, its working. If you want use data-entity_id="8913" then use  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[data-entity_id='8913']")).click();